# !! functions: Failed to load function definition from source: Error: spawn "E:\Firebase Function (Todour)\functions\venv\Scripts\activate.bat" ENOENT

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I want to run an emulator for Firebase Function, but I get this error

I used this command:
`firebase emulators:start --project test`

in the terminal I received the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd182.png)

I don't understand how to solve this problem.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: Read the error messages. Do you understand what `activate.bat` is and Python virtual environments [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)? You did not include details on how your project is setup.